# Search and replace a variable word

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, search, replace

I'm looking for a program which can create a text block with a different variable string every time.

I've tried doing this in certain languages, but I'd rather have a text editor which can do this.

Example: A list of words are chosen to replace a variable in a piece of text, that piece of text is then reprinted for every word.

I like Ice cream.

Ice cream is great.

Don't eat too much Ice cream.

---

I like Banana.

Banana is great.

Don't eat too much Banana.

---

I like Apple.

Apple is great.

Don't eat too much Apple.

---

I tried doing this in a programming language (AS3) but it doesn`t support multi-line strings very well.

What I`m looking for is either a text editor program (for Windows) which can do this, or a AS3 code snippet which can do this. (Which supports multi-line without the need of manually having to put \n everywhere.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what to suggest for the multi-line issue - that's just how it is and you have to add `\n` or `<br />` (in HTML text boxes).

As for the replace, that's a straightforward process. Just set up some type of token that you can replace in the text, e.g.

```
var str:String = "I like {}.\n{} is great.\nDon't eat too much {}.";
```

Then you can do either:

```
str.split("{}").join("Banana");
```

Or:

```
str.replace(/\{\}/g, "Banana");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am also looking for a text editor solution since adding \n is annoying when dealing with big blocks of text.

Comment: @user1508405 PHP doesn't mind multi-line strings, so you can use that to take a multi-line string and then replace the newlines with `\n` before you paste into Flash.

Answer (score 0):

The String Class has three handy methods for working with patterns and strings. These three methods are also case sensitive, meaning uppercase and lowercase matter when searching.

1. match()
2. search()
3. replace()

   ```
   var string1:String = "Hello World!";
   var subString:String = "Hell";

   trace(string1.match(subString));
   trace(string1.search(subString));
   trace(string1.replace(subString, "Jell"));
   ```

**match()** method will display the substring if it is found and null if not found. The **search()** method will give a value of zero( 0 ) if the method finds the substing, and a value of negative one ( -1) if not found. The **replace()** method will replace the target substring with a new substring if the substring is found. You can also make the value nothing to simply remove an unwanted part of a string.

we can run conditionals like this:

```
    var string1:String = "Hello World!";
    var subString:String = "Hell";

    if (string1.search(subString) == 0) {
        trace(subString + " is in the string, I can now replace it or remove it.");
    } else {
        trace(subString + " is not in this string.");
    }
```